# Unusual error in jQuery HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, post, arcgis

I have to make two HTTP POST request.
Below is the first request.

```
function getJobId() {
    var url = "https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/submitJob";

    $.post(url, parameters, function (data, status) {
        console.log("Response => ", data);
        var responseObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var jobId = $.trim(responseObj.jobId);
        console.log("JobId => ", jobId);
        console.log("JobId length => ", jobId.length);
        getOutStops(jobId);
    });
}
```

Based on the response that I get from this request I make another POST request with the jobId that I get above.
Below is the code for the 2nd POST request.

```
function getOutStops(jobId) {
    // Assume jobId = "adhasjdn123123" 
    var url = "https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/jobs/" + jobId + "/results/out_stops";
    // when I append the jobId to the URL it gives 400 error. 
    // But when I hardcode the jobId to URL for eg:
    // var url = "https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/jobs/adhasjdn123123/results/out_stops";
    // The above URL is giving successful output. Even tho both are same.
    // not sure why??
    $.post(url, params, function (data, status) {
        console.log("responseText => ", data);
        var responseObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var stopList = responseObj.value.features;
        parseStops(stopList);
    });
}
```

When I append the jobId and make a request then it is throwing 400 error. But when I hardcode the url for eg:

```
var url = "https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/jobs/1234567890/results/out_stops";
```

Then I get successful output.

Not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: `console.log("JobId => ", jobId);` Does this output what you expect? Is the length correct in the next (malformed here) log output? have you tried console.log the url? have you checked the developer tools network tab to make sure the url is correct? By the way, this isn't the first time I've seen odd behaviour when there's a jQuery.post within the callback of a jQuery.post

Comment: `console.log("JobId length => ", jobId.` Isn't this a syntax error?

Comment: jobId gives the correct result. When i hardcode the jobId in the 2nd POST request URL then i get the successful response. But when i append it I am getting 400.
I also checked the length its the same. I have checked for network calls too.
I logged the URL too and the jobId is successfully getting appended.

Comment: console.log the url to be sure ... and check the developer tools console/network tabs to be sure too

Comment: @sanoopsandy might be your jobId has unwanted spaces around it, try trimming it, jobId = $.trim( responseObj.jobId );

Comment: console.log(url); check what it gives. do trim if spaces are seen in url.

Comment: I have tried $.trim on the jobId.
This is the response from 1st POST request. 
    Response =>{"jobId":"asdjabsd123123","jobStatus":"esriJobSubmitted"}

Console.log("URL => ", url) gives: 
https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/jobs/asdjabsd123123/results/out_stops
I get following response from it. 
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":[]}}

Comment: [400 Bad Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error): *The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, too large size, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)*

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Please read the comment that I have added to the code recently. I guess you didn't understand the problem that I am facing.

Comment: @sanoopsandy Sorry, I understood you were getting a `400 Bad Request` status code in the server response and I explained what it meant (lots of people prefer to just ignore error messages), my excuses if that's not the case (but please edit the info out if it isn't correct).

Comment: As about your code, it's very dangerous (and hard to maintain) to populate a global variable right from asynchronous code. You're assuming the URL is the same but it clearly is not.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález As far as I understand the jobId is passed as a parameter to the second function and when I print the jobId in the logs I get the expected jobId. 
If what I am doing is wrong please suggest the correct way to go about it.

Comment: 1) When you compose `url` dynamically, add a break point it inspect it (or type `console.log(url)` in the next line). 2) I'd consider refactoring code to make `jobId` local to the callback function (unless it's just a typo and you simply forgot the `var` prefix).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have edited the code. I remove the global variables as you suggested and even logged the URL. I get the complete URL with the passed jobId and still get 400 response. When I try the logged URL in postman I get successful response.

Comment: So you've tried `console.log(url)` and the generated URL that fails is the same char-by-char to the hard-coded that doesn't?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes and it is so weird. The same url which i get after console.log(url) I use it to make a POST request in postman and it gives me correct response. Never faced a issue like this.

Comment: I'm facing the same error. This is very strange. Please someone help.